# Implicit conversion from data type ntext to varchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I get the above error in one of my SQL Server 2000 stored procedure. Here I do not use any variables with type `ntext`. I do not know why I get this error. Can some one help?

Comment: can you post the code that is generating the error?

Comment: You may be not using a variable of datatype `NTEXT`, but you are certainly trying to do an implicit cast from a column that is `NTEXT` to a `VARCHAR`, the error is really clear. If you need more help, then post your sp and the structure of the tables that it uses

Comment: @bluefeet Additional Info. I have a varchar(8000) parameter for the SP. I get this error only when the input exceeds 8000 characters. Any suggestions on what data type to use, in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the problem is not with the stored procedure at all. As you said on your comment, the error happens when the input exceeds 8000 characters. SQL Server 2000 doesn't have `VARCHAR(MAX)`, the maximum length for `VARCHAR` is 8000. So, if you try to pass a longer string to your sp, it need to do a conversion to `TEXT`, but it can't be an implicit conversion, so you need a parameter of type `TEXT`. Of course, you would need to change your sp, and there are many operations that can't be done on a column of this datatype, so you may be unable to actually do what you want.